# Capitalisation of "Hall effect"

Tags: proper-nouns

How should I capitalise *Hall effect*? I am using this in a brochure and want to get the capitalisation right.

I am certain that *Hall* is capitalised, as this phenomenon (concerning the behaviour of electrical currents near magnets) was named after its discoverer, Mr. Hall.

But what about *effect*? Should it too be capitalised?

Comment: Generally, follow the policies of the place you are writing.  In mathematics, some journals would want *Zorn's Lemma*, while other would want *Zorn's lemma*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should properly name it *the Hall effect.*

For more info read [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) to understand how it should be used in sentences.
Examples:

At the beginning of a sentence:

> The Hall effect was discovered in 1879.

In the middle of a sentence:

> One very important feature of the Hall effect is that it differentiates between positive charges moving in one direction and negative charges moving in the opposite.

At the end of a sentence:

> The absence of the free transverse boundaries renders the interpretation of the Corbino effect simpler than that of the Hall effect.

Used as an adjective in a sentence:

> Hall effect devices produce a very low signal level and thus require amplification.

Comment: Thanks for your really fast response. I had seen that article but I've seen plenty of bad English elsewhere in Wikipedia, so wanted confirmation that this particular article is following accepted grammar rules.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the examples I took from the articles. You can safely follow them.

Answer (score -1):

I do see just one error. If indeed the second word in "Hall effect" is not (necessarily) capitalized, then this implies that "Hall effect" is not a proper noun, and hyphenation rules for compound modifiers will apply. Thus, the last example should read "Hall-effect devices produce ..."